# Is there a way to find out what information a website is tracking from you?

Tags: security, tracking

I think I remember there used to be a scanner of sorts that scans a website and tells you in ways how the website is tracking you or what information it knows about you. Can't remember what the site was called.

Comment: yes you should!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are myriad browser plugins, including [disconnect](https://disconnect.me) and [Collusion](https://disconnect.me/tools), which can show you what is being tracked.

Comment: The link to Collusion if anyone is interested: http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/collusion/

Comment: I've added the general one - it's also on disconnect.me.